# NumberLong is missing when mongoexport to json file

Tags: mongodb, mongoexport

I used the mongoexport to export a collection to json file (script as below).

`mongoexport -d db1 -c user --out /root/user_130226.json`

Found that those parameters with type "NumberLong" were saved without word "NumberLong", so when I use mongoimport, the word "NumberLong" is missing too.

Same if using mongodump and mongorestore.

Example:

source :

`>> "cd" : NumberLong(1361862291)`

output and imported to new collection :

`>> "cd" : 1361862291`

But if the NumberLong with quote in bracket (), the it exported and imported accordingly.

Example:

> > "u4" : NumberLong("111018951303058"),

Questions:

## 1. Does it matter if the word "NumberLong" is not being exported ?

## 2. Is it correct to save the NumberLong without quote ?

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Is it correct to save the NumberLong without quote ?

It seem like it's the behavior of Mongo, depending on the length of the number. Did further test by parse in different length of number.

1. 44 - no quote >> NumberLong(44),
2. 1338585352 - no quote >> NumberLong(1338585352),
3. 13385853520 - quote added >> "NumberLong("13385853520")

> 1. Does it matter if the word "NumberLong" is not being exported ?

Since with or without quote are correct and it's behavior of Mongo. Hence NumberLong() will be removed when exporting with using mongoexport/mongodump should consider correct too.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Does it matter if the word "NumberLong" is not being exported ?

Depends, does it matter to you?

The reason why `mmongoexport` is dong this is because, unlike BSON, JSON does not have the capability to express the advanced objects like `NumberLong` that BSON can; with this in mind they are simply stripped.

If you intend to import this file back into MongoDB it could matter to you since the objects will be lost.

> 1. Is it correct to save the NumberLong without quote ?

Yes, `NumberLong` can take a positive integer as its sole parameter.

Comment: For #1, I did used mongodump to output as BSON file, but it is same result (as mongoimport) that <u>NumberLong without quote ""</u> is missing when use mongorestore to import back the BSON to DB. If <u>"NumberLong with quote"</u>, then it can dump and restore correctly.

Comment: @Cthoong If mongodump is missing objects when you reimport it then there is something wrong